# Where is a good guide to remote participation in the Ubuntu Developer Summit, and is it upgraded with each summit?

Tags: community, uds

Is there a guide to properly participating in UDS remotely?

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The UDS website](http://uds.ubuntu.com/) contains all the information you require.

[This section](http://uds.ubuntu.com/participate/remote/) covers remote participation.

The key thing to remember - [all schedule times](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/) are in US day-light savings time - set your clock carefully!

Have fun.